# Selecting last 2 rows of each dense_rank

Tags: sql-server, row-number

Using MSSQL, I am trying to get some information from a journal where one event happens directly after another event.

So what I am effectively aiming for, is to get a row number partitioned by a TransactionID, and then I need the last 2 rows (last 2 row number) for EACH transactionID (Ordered by a TxnDate field). There could be any number of rows per TransactionID.

So I would get:

```
JnlId    TxnId    RowNum
5        10001    65
2        10001    66
10       10002    11
8        10002    12
5        10003    15
98       10003    16
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this as I am at a loss! The end game after this is to filter out the 'JnlId' field for a select few of IDs.

Bit of a back story. This customer thinks their staff is stealing, so I need to filter out when they are cancelling items directly before finishing off each transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I added some extra rows to make dense rank more obvious:

Test data:

```
DECLARE @t table(JnlId int,TxnId int,RowNum int,  TxnDate date)
INSERT @t values
(5, 10001,65, '2015-01-01'),
(2, 10001,66, '2015-01-02'),
(2, 10001,66, '2015-01-03'),
(2, 10001,66, '2015-01-04'),
(2, 10001,67, '2015-01-04'),
(2, 10001,67, '2015-01-04'),
(10,10002,11, '2015-01-03'),
(8, 10002,12, '2015-01-04'),
(5, 10003,15, '2015-01-05'),
(98,10003,16, '2015-01-06')
```

Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() over(partition by txnID order by TxnDate desc) rn,
    JnlId,  TxnId,  RowNum, TxnDate
  FROM @t
)
SELECT JnlId,  TxnId,  RowNum, TxnDate FROM CTE
WHERE rn<=2
```

Result:

```
JnlId  TxnId  RowNum  TxnDate
2      10001  66      2015-01-04
2      10001  67      2015-01-04
2      10001  67      2015-01-04
2      10001  66      2015-01-03
8      10002  12      2015-01-04
10     10002  11      2015-01-03
98     10003  16      2015-01-06
5      10003  15      2015-01-05
```

Comment: Thank you! The way I did it was horrendously long! (90 lines long!). It worked, but wasn't exactly professional like this way!! Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **ordering** in `ascending` order try `descending` order

```
select * from 
(
select dense_rank() over(partition by transactionID Order by TxnDate Desc) Rn,*
from yourtable
) A
where rn<=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just order by RowNum descending and then select what has ROW_NUMBER less or equals 2

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    JnlId INT
    , TxnId INT
    , RowNum INT
);

INSERT INTO @Table
    (JnlId, TxnId, RowNum)
VALUES
    (5, 10001, 65)
    , (2, 10001, 66)
    , (10, 10002, 11)
    , (8, 10002, 12)
    , (5, 10003, 15)
    , (98, 10003, 16);

SELECT T.JnlId, T.TxnId, T.RowNum
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TxnId ORDER BY RowNum DESC) AS RowNo, *
FROM @Table) AS T
WHERE T.RowNo <=2
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! So much better than how I did it on mine!